# Updating same table with trigger on insert

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

One of our tables has a column for saving troubleshooting information, it is an XML data type, pertaining to the row so if an issue arises we can quickly see everything that happened for that transaction. This has become an issue because it grows the database size drastically. After a month there is generally no need to retrieve this information and it is wasting valuable space.

Our solution is to null out the XML log column after it is a month old by using an insert trigger. Our concern is, will this affect the performance of the table enough to be noticeable and potentially cause problems?

Below is what we are trying to achieve:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_ClearTransactionXmlLogs]
AS
    UPDATE [dbo].[CCResponse]
       SET [TransactionXML] = NULL
     WHERE [DateSaved] < DATEADD(MONTH,-1,GETDATE())
       AND [TransactionXML] IS NOT NULL; 

CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[tr_ClearTransactionXmlLogs]
ON [dbo].[CCResponse]
AFTER INSERT
AS EXEC sp_ClearTransactionXmlLogs;
```

Comment: Which database? Can you add tags for it?

Comment: SQL Server 2008 R2 Express

Comment: Thank you everyone for your input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than having this run as a trigger every time an insert happens, why not schedule it as a nightly job, part of your database maintenance jobs?

Comment: That is another we are considering. I am just wondering if there would be any performance issues with going this route.

Comment: Depending on how many records there are, and how long it takes to update the table, there will be performance issues on insert. It should be your requirements that drive the decision. If you do N number of inserts per day, is there really a need to run the update N times. If your DateSaved does not take into account Time, then running the update more than once a day is pointless.

Comment: On the initial addition of adding the trigger/procedure, it takes upwards of 10 minutes to clear out 100k+ rows. However, on each insert only 1-10 rows are affected and the time lapse is unnoticeable.

Answer (score 0):

Usually triggers are used to perform an action after the main operation (insert, update, delete) about the record changed.

If you don't execute any insert, your CCResponse remail with TransactionXML not null.

Instead of trigger, IMHO, I use a planned job.

Comment: The concept we are going for is to clean out month old log data. Rows are only inserted into this table and never updated or deleted so running the "cleanup" after an insert seemed most logical.

Comment: As far as scheduling a job goes, this is the express version of SQL Server 2008 R2 and does not have the ability to run SQL Agent as far as I know. I agree scheduling a nightly maintenance job would be the ideal option but it doesn't seem possible with Express. I've tested the trigger option and I don't notice any noticeable performance issues currently and I was curious about the long run.

Comment: You don't need SQL Server Agent in order to have code executed against the SQL server on a scheduled time. One way to go around this is to have a simple binary or script which connects to the SQL database and executes a stored procedure containing all your maintenance tasks. You could use Task Scheduler to control when this fires. Either way, performing a task on during operation which is not related/necessary for that operation is a poor design choice.